# Python pandas, Plotting options for multiple lines

Tags: python, plot, pandas

I want to plot multiple lines from a pandas dataframe and setting different options for each line. I would like to do something like

```
testdataframe=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))
testdataframe.plot(style=['s-','o-','^-'],color=['b','r','y'],linewidth=[2,1,1])
```

This will raise some error messages:

- linewidth is not callable with a list
- In style I can't use 's' and 'o' or any other alphabetical symbol, when defining colors in a list

Also there is some more stuff which seems weird to me

- when I add another plot command to the above code `testdataframe[0].plot()` it will plot this line in the same plot, if I add the command `testdataframe[[0,1]].plot()` it will create a new plot
- If i would call `testdataframe[0].plot(style=['s-','o-','^-'],color=['b','r','y'])` it is fine with a list in style, but not with a list in color

Hope somebody can help, thanks.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You're so close!

You can specify the colors in the styles list:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

testdataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
styles = ['bs-','ro-','y^-']
linewidths = [2, 1, 4]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col, style, lw in zip(testdataframe.columns, styles, linewidths):
    testdataframe[col].plot(style=style, lw=lw, ax=ax)
```

Also note that the `plot` method can take a `matplotlib.axes` object, so you can make multiple calls like this (if you want to):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

testdataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
testdataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(4,3)), columns=['D', 'E', 'F'])
styles1 = ['bs-','ro-','y^-']
styles2 = ['rs-','go-','b^-']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
testdataframe1.plot(style=styles1, ax=ax)
testdataframe2.plot(style=styles2, ax=ax)
```

Not really practical in this case, but the concept might come in handy later.

Comment: thx for your help, but this does not help with the line width? also I want to use some self defined color like own_color='#FF0000' and then it is not callable that way.

Comment: then i can only think to iterate through the columns. see my edits to the first example.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm using right now. But I just wonder if their is only this clumsy way for such a straight forward task. But great thanks for your help!!

Comment: This is a good answer, but to @Joerg's point is there not a stream-lined way to do this with just a couple lines of code? It's a seemingly easy task.

Comment: @zthomas.nc you probably want to use seaborn if you're doing something like this a lot

Comment: My colors are hex strings, so this approach does not work for me. I get strange behavior when specifying both color and style separately.

Comment: @CPBL, hexstring colors won't work if specifying the style in a whole string like e.g., "rs-" for "red squares and a solid line"

Answer (score 28):

So I think the answer lies in passing the color and style in the same argument. The following example works with pandas 0.19.2:

```
testdataframe=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))
testdataframe.plot(style=['r*-','bo-','y^-'], linewidth=2.0)
```

Unfortunately, it seems that passing multiple line widths as an input to matplotlib is not possible.

Comment: this is why you always scroll all the way down.

Answer (score 23):

Considering the dataframe `testdataframe`

```
testdataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))

print(testdataframe)

   0   1   2
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11
```

You can combine `styles` into a single list of strings as in `styles` defined below.  I'll also define the linewidths in `lws`

```
styles=['bs-', 'ro-', 'y^-']
lws = [2, 1, 1]
```

We can use the `plot` method on the `testdataframe` passing the list `styles` to the `style` parameter.  Note that we could have also passed a dictionary (and probably other things as well).

However, line widths are not as easily handled.  I first capture the `AxesSubplot` object and iterate over the lines attribute setting the line width.

```
ax = testdataframe.plot(style=styles)
for i, l in enumerate(ax.lines):
    plt.setp(l, linewidth=lws[i])
```

[image]