# plot pandas dataframe two columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i have a pandas dataframe which has dates as indexes and some columns:
I would like to plot a line chart with 2 lines (let's say 'ISP.MI' and 'Ctrv'); on the x axis I need the 'Date'

```
Ticker       ISP.MI  Daily returns        Ctrv  Inv_Am  Giac_Media
Date                                                                 
2016-01-01  2.90117            NaN  100.000000     100       100.0   
2016-01-04  2.80159      -0.034927  196.507301     200       150.0   
2016-01-05  2.85608       0.019263  300.292610     300       200.0   
2016-01-06  2.77904      -0.027345  392.081255     400       250.0   
2016-01-07  2.73206      -0.017050  485.396411     500       300.0   
2016-01-08  2.72267      -0.003443  583.725246     600       350.0
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you dont care about axis scale:

```
plt.figure()

x = df['Date']
y1 = df['ISP.MI']
y2 = df['Ctrv']

plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
```

if you do care about it:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

x = df['Date']
y1 = df['ISP.MI']
y2 = df['Ctrv']

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-')
```

Answer (score 56):

I think the simpliest is select columns by subset and then [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df[['ISP.MI','Ctrv']].plot()
```

Comment: How do u add the style and color of lines for each column as a list e.g. g-, ro etc. Can u pls add to the answer. @jezrael

Comment: @ihightower - there are multiple solutions for it, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179954/2901002) answers.

Comment: @jezrael Any idea on how to save a plot created this way? I used `plt.savefig ("path/pic1.png")` it just saves a blank image.

Comment: If you're not able to see multiple column lines / points, then check the `dtypes` of the dataframe and convert it from `object` to numeric columns. This issue wasted at least a few hours for me.

Answer (score 17):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'x' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
     'y_one' : np.random.rand(10),
     'y_two' : np.random.rand(10)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.plot('x',y=['y_one','y_two'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I find this approach useful since it shows how `plot()` can be used to select specific columns from the DataFrame and map the designated columns to the X & Y axis.

Answer (score 2):

So, here is the code that from scratch creates a dataframe that looks like yours and generates the plot you asked for:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# The following two lines are not mandatory for the code to work
import matplotlib.style as style
style.use('dark_background')

def create_datetime_range(numdays=10):
    """Creates the timestamp range"""
    base = datetime.datetime.today()
    datelist = pd.date_range(base, periods=numdays).to_pydatetime()
    return datelist
def convert_to_date(datetime_list):
    """Converts a timestamp array into a date array"""
    return [x.date() for x in datetime_list]



a = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'ISP.MI': np.random.normal(2,1,10),
        'Ctrv' : np.random.normal(200,150,10)
    }, 
    index=convert_to_date(create_date_range())
)
a.plot()
```

[image]

However, I believe that your dataframe is different in two ways:

1. It seems that there are two levels in the index (the Date title seems on a second row to the Ticker title). I imagine this could be because you used something like .groupby() or .unstack() or other aggregation/pivoting method. I suggest you to look in the reset_index() method.

2.Your dataframe has more columns that you need. As suggested by @jezrael, you should first select only these. You can do it with something like:

```
df[['ISP.MI','Ctrv']]
```

and then using the .plot() method on the smaller dataframe and let pandas handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Now in latest pandas you can directly use df.plot.scatter function

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 0], [7.0, 3.2, 1],
               [6.4, 3.2, 1], [5.9, 3.0, 2]],
              columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])
ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='length',
                  y='width',
                  c='DarkBlue')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html