# Plotting dataframe with one line different

Tags: python, pandas

I saw this post: [Python pandas, Plotting options for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178194/python-pandas-plotting-options-for-multiple-lines)
for plotting different options for multiple lines.

I have a dataframe. I would only like one column, the first, to be plotted differently than the others (bolded and dashed). Is there a way to do this? Currently I'm doing something like

df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))

df.plot()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `matplotlib.pyplot` (integrated into pandas) you can specify your columns with the df.`iloc()` function and then specifying line style and thickness.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3))

plt.plot(df.iloc[:,0], '--', linewidth=3)
plt.plot(df.iloc[:,1:], '-', color='green')
plt.show()
```

[image]