# How to customize colors on a mulitline plot with both markers and errorbars specified

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, markers

I followed someone's tip here on how to plot a dataframe with both custom markers AND error bars. However, I don't know how to change the colors of each line in the plot.

I've tried using passing "style" and "color" but it doesn't let me specify both.

```
tumor = pd.DataFrame({
'Time': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
'Capomulin': [45.0, 44.26608641544399, 43.08429058188399, 42.06431734681251, 40.71632532212173, 39.93952782686818],
'Infubinol': [45.0, 47.062001033088, 49.40390857087143, 51.29639655633334, 53.19769093422999, 55.71525236228889],
'Ketapril': [45.0, 47.38917452114348, 49.582268974622714, 52.39997374321578, 54.92093473734737, 57.678981717731574],
'Placebo': [45.0, 47.125589188437495, 49.42332947868749, 51.35974169802999, 54.36441702681052, 57.48257374394706]})
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

tsem = pd.DataFrame({
'Time': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
'Capomulin': [0.0, 0.44859285020103756, 0.7026843745238932, 0.8386172472985688, 0.9097306924832056, 0.8816421535181787],
'Infubinol': [0.0, 0.23510230430767506, 0.2823459146215716, 0.35770500497539054, 0.4762095134790833, 0.5503145721542003],
'Ketapril': [0.0, 0.26481852016728674, 0.35742125637213723, 0.5802679659678779, 0.7264838239834724, 0.7554127528910378],
'Placebo': [0.0, 0.21809078325219497, 0.40206380730509245, 0.6144614435805993, 0.8396091719248746, 1.0348719877946384]})
errors.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

ax = tumor.plot(linewidth = .5, yerr = tsem, legend = False)
ax.set_prop_cycle(None)
tumor.plot(linewidth = .5, 
style =["o-", "^-", "s-", "d-"], 
color = ["r", "b", "g", "k"], ax = ax)

plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Time (Days)")
plt.ylabel("Tumor Volume (mm3)")

plt.show()
```

I expect to get a multiline graph with the specified colors, markers, and errorbars.

However, I get this error:

ValueError: Cannot pass 'style' string with a color symbol and 'color' keyword argument. Please use one or the other or pass 'style' without a color symbol

The resulting graph only shows the error bars and lines but no markers.

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAhMj.jpg)

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxURZ.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pandas, Plotting options for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178194/python-pandas-plotting-options-for-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
style =["ro-", "b^-", "gs-", "kd-"]
```

The reason for *either* style *or* color is, that style strings (can) contain color information, too.

Note that you should replace `df` by `tumor` and `error` by `tsem` to let the plots be created over time.

Comment: Thank you! 

Adding the color letter for each marker to the "style" argument worked like a charm. 

The one other thing I had to do was add the "color" argument to the "ax =" to make sure the same colors were overlaid each time. 

Cheers :D