# change individual linestyle when using pandas's plot

Tags: python, pandas

I have many dataframes(df) which have multiple varying number of columns and the first column is date, the rest of columns are the data I like to plot. I used df.plot() to plot the lines automatically. It is simple to use panda's plot function directly. However, for example, I like to change the linewidth of the first and 4th line or even only the first line. How to do it in pandas?   I know how to do it using matplotlib by looping over each column to plot each line. what about just using pandas's plot function? Thanks

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think that you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178194/python-pandas-plotting-options-for-multiple-lines

Comment: Thanks Bricam. Yes it is very close to what I wanted. I forgot to mention that sometimes the number of columns in my dataframe is changing, but I only want to change some specific columns.  How to deal with it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas, Plotting options for multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178194/python-pandas-plotting-options-for-multiple-lines)

Comment: Thanks Trenton and Bricam. Yes it is very close to what I wanted. I forgot to mention that sometimes the number of columns in my dataframe is changing, but I only want to change some specific columns. For example, in the example you referred, the linewidth list has 3 number for 3 lines.  linewidth=[2,1,1] . what about I have 10 data dataframes and the number of columns is unknown and changing for each dataframe. It means I have to used vary length of lists for linewidth. How to deal with it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a list with a fixed lenght size (depending of your DataFrame size):

```
list_of_line_width = [1] * len(df.columns)
```

The rest is just changing the size of the lines you are looking for:

```
list_of_line_width[index_position] = lenght_of_the_line
```

Comment: Thanks Bricam. It is what I wanted. I appreciate it
list_of_line_width = [1] * len(df.columns)